# Is there anyway to tell if gzip is in fact compressing specific files?

Tags: javascript, css, compression, gzip, deflate

I know I have gzip running on my server and site. Most everything is taken care of but when I run firebug or google pagespeed, I am told that certain CSS files (hosted by me) are not being gzipped and could be greatly compressed.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

### Update

I was asked about my server: MediaTemple DV 3.5 running CentOS 5 with PHP 5.3.2 and Apache 2.2.15

Comment: It might help to know the web server you are running.

Comment: This can be easily determined by using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) is great for this purpose. Simply navigate to your site and in the `Net` tab inspect the Response headers for all requests. For example here's a properly gzipped CSS (on StackOverflow of course):

[image]

You could also install the [YSlow plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/) and it will tell you exactly which static resources could be compressed in order to reduce bandwidth.

Comment: weird - according to Firebug, the css that Pagespeed (run in google chrome browser) shows as gzipped.

Comment: @JM4 Same here.  Page speed seems to take a while to sort itself out.  The audit tab in Chrome seems to be more consistent.